# The installation or removal of a software package failed

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center, software-installation

I recently updated to ubuntu 13.04, after installing some random program from the software-center I get the "Package operation failed"- "The installation or removal of a software package failed." and it looks like it has to do with python 3.3.
Can someone explain what is this all about.(note that the random program was installed)

[full paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5716919/)

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package zenmap.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%

----------

Unpacking zenmap (from .../zenmap_6.00-0.3_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Setting up python3.3-minimal (3.3.1-1ubuntu5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py", line 8, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/imp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tokenize.py", line 28, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 122, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
dpkg: error processing python3.3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.3-minimal (>= 3.3.1-1~); however:
  Package python3.3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.3:
 python3.3 depends on python3.3-minimal (= 3.3.1-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package python3.3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.3 (>= 3.3.1-1~); however:
  Package python3.3 is not configured yet.
 python3 depends on python3-minimal (= 3.3.1-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-minimal is not configured yet.
----------
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.3-minimal
 python3-minimal
 python3.3
 python3
 python3-apt
 python3-dbus
 language-selector-common
 python3-gi
 bluez
 gnome-menus
 kde-runtime
 kdenlive
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 gnome-control-center
 python3-xkit
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-crypto
 python3-oauthlib
 friends-dispatcher
 libfriends0
 lsb-release
 ubuntu-minimal
 python3-gdbm:i386
 python3-commandnotfound
 command-not-found
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 ubuntu-standard
 ufw
 update-manager-core
 python3-problem-report
 python3-apport
 apport
 apport-gtk
 apturl-common
 unattended-upgrades
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
 python3-aptdaemon
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 software-properties-gtk
 apturl
Setting up zenmap (6.00-0.3) ...
Setting up python3.3-minimal (3.3.1-1ubuntu5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: same problem [here][1]:
solved by 
Gx1sptDTDa



  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316189/broken-dependencies-after-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

If you have Synaptic Package Manager installed open it, then select "broken" on the left side. Uninstall or reinstall the broken package.

I was showing libmotif4 as a broken package. Turned out I had libmotif3 installed as well and this was causing an issue. I removed libmotif3 and reinstalled 4.

Comment: Maybe in "Fix broken packages" from the menu..

Comment: In my case it was an incorrectly set environment variable in `/etc/environment` 
e.g. VAR = "test" 
The spaces between the equal sign were illegal.
Once removed it allowed the software updates to proceed without issues.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```