# cannot install python3 after dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, dpkg, python3

How can I install python3?

I try to install python3 like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

But I get the error below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apport-symptoms caribou digikam-data enblend enfuse finger gcc-4.7-base:i386 gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-muffin-3.0
  gir1.2-signon-1.0 gnome-applets-data gnome-media gstreamer0.10-gconf icoutils kde-runtime-data kipi-plugins-common lib32z1 libc6-i386
  libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkcalcore4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw21 libkdeclarative5 libkdesu5 libkdnssd4
  libkexiv2-11 libkexiv2-data libkface-data libkface1 libkgeomap-data libkgeomap1 libkipi-data libkipi9 libkmediaplayer4 libknotifyconfig4 libksane-data
  libksane0 libkvkontakte1 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblensfun-data liblensfun0 libmail-sendmail-perl libmarblewidget14 libmediawiki1 libmuffin0
  libnemo-extension1 libnepomuksync4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libopencv-calib3d2.3 libopencv-core2.3 libopencv-features2d2.3 libopencv-flann2.3
  libopencv-highgui2.3 libopencv-imgproc2.3 libopencv-legacy2.3 libopencv-objdetect2.3 libopencv-video2.3 libplasma3 libplot2c2 libqapt-runtime libqapt1
  librpmbuild3 librpmsign1 libsys-hostname-long-perl libthreadweaver4 muffin-common ncurses-term nepomuk-core ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme pax
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript po-debconf python-gpgme python-lxml rpm shared-desktop-ontologies
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up python3.3-minimal (3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py", line 8, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/imp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tokenize.py", line 28, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 122, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
dpkg: error processing python3.3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.3-minimal (>= 3.3.1-1~); however:
  Package python3.3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.3:
 python3.3 depends on python3.3-minimal (= 3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package python3.3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.3 (>= 3.3.1-1~); however:
  Package python3.3 is not configured yet.
 python3 depends on python3-minimal (= 3.3.2-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.4); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.3); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.3); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.4); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:
 bluez depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing bluez (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-release:
 lsb-release depends on python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing lsb-release (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apt:
 python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.3); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.4); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on gnome-menus (>= 2.12.0); however:
  Package gnome-menus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
 indicator-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 indicator-bluetooth depends on gnome-control-center | ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package gnome-control-center is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.
 indicator-bluetooth depends on gnome-bluetooth | ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.

dpkg: error processing indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-user-share:
 gnome-user-share depends on gnome-bluetooth; however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gnome-user-share (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pkg-resources:
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3 (>= 3.2); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3 (<< 3.4); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-defer:
 python3-defer depends on python3 (>= 3.2); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-defer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon:
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-defer (>= 1.0.6); however:
  Package python3-defer is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python3-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-printer-gnome:
 system-config-printer-gnome depends on packagekit-system-interface; however:
  Package packagekit-system-interface is not installed.
  Package python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat which provides packagekit-system-interface is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing system-config-printer-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptdaemon:
 aptdaemon depends on python3:any (>= 3.2); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 aptdaemon depends on python3.3; however:
  Package python3.3 is not configured yet.
 aptdaemon depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 aptdaemon depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.3-minimal
 python3-minimal
 python3.3
 python3
 python3-gi
 python3-dbus
 bluez
 lsb-release
 python3-apt
 gnome-menus
 gnome-control-center
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 gnome-user-share
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-defer
 python3-aptdaemon
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
 system-config-printer-gnome
 aptdaemon
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I do:

```
sudo dpkg --configure python3
```

I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.3 (>= 3.3.1-1~); however:
  Package python3.3 is not configured yet.
 python3 depends on python3-minimal (= 3.3.2-14ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-minimal is not configured yet.
 python3 depends on dh-python; however:
  Package dh-python is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
```

And when I do:

```
sudo dpkg --configure python3.3-minimal
```

I get:

```
Setting up python3.3-minimal (3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py", line 8, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/imp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tokenize.py", line 28, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 122, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
dpkg: error processing python3.3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.3-minimal
```

EDIT after comment by user193537:

When I try to remove python3:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3
```

Then I get this dependency problem:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3.3-minimal (3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py", line 8, in <module>
    import imp
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/imp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tokenize.py", line 28, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 122, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
dpkg: error processing python3.3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.3:
 python3.3 depends on python3.3-minimal (= 3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package python3.3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.3-minimal
 python3.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered by @Gx1sptDTDa here:

[Broken dependencies after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316189/broken-dependencies-after-upgrade)

Gx1sptDTDa links to:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1165281
```

The solution is to edit these files:

```
/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_constants.py
/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py
/usr/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py
```

In sre_constants.py I replace:

```
from _sre import MAXREPEAT
```

with:

```
MAXREPEAT = 65535
#from _sre import MAXREPEAT
```

In sre_parse.py and sre_compile.py I comment out:

```
from _sre import MAXREPEAT
```